# Django Rest API: How to get rid of 'UUID' in json when serializing models?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Why does 'UUID' appear in front of the value of 'profile' key and how do I remove it properly?

roster/serializers.py

```
class ShiftSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

class Meta:
    model = Shift
    fields = ('id', 'profile', 'location', 'date', 'start_time', 'end_time')
```

profile/models.py

```
class Profile(models.Models):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=True)
```

roster/models.py

```
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=True)
    profile = models.ForeignKey('profiles.Profile', null=True, blank=True)
```

python manage.py shell

```
from roster.models import Shift
from roster.serializers import ShiftSerializer

myshift = Shift.objects.first()
serializer = ShiftSerializer(myshift)
serializer.data
```

Output:

```
{'id': '92ca258e-8624-434a-b61d-e1cd3b80e0e8', 'profile': UUID('0081b028-0a11-47fb-971e-c47177ed93be')
```

Comment: Why would you want to remove it ? It'll be correctly rendered by the json renderer.

Comment: You're absolutely correct! Thank you!

Comment: You question makes sense @meowmeow. Because what we expect from a serializer output are native types.  `UUID` is not a native type.

This also causes me a problem when I write test checking that what I post on an endpoint produce a correct json, when I use DRF:  `self.assertDictEqual(posted_data,  produced_data)`. Because it will compare a UUID in a string, with a UUID() object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite `representation` ,like this

```
class ShiftSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Shift
        fields = '__all__'

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        return {
            "id": obj.id,
            "profile": obj.profile.id,
            "location": obj.location,
            "date": obj.date,
            "start_time": obj.start_time,
        }
```

Answer (score 19):

**tl;dr**

See **The solution** at the bottom.

**The problem**

Attribute `.data` on Serializer should return only primitive representation of object (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#baseserializer). This should be done by calling `to_representation()` method (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#to_representationself-obj) on a serializer and all fields.

```
@six.add_metaclass(SerializerMetaclass)
class Serializer(BaseSerializer):

    # ...
    # ...

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        """
        Object instance -> Dict of primitive datatypes.
        """
        # ...
        # ...

        for field in fields:

            # ...
            # ...

            if check_for_none is None:
                ret[field.field_name] = None
            else:
                ret[field.field_name] = field.to_representation(attribute)

        return ret
```

Source: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L505-L529

There is a problem with models that have `uuid.UUID` as a primary key. `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` returns `uuid.UUID` instance - this is clearly not a primitive type which leads to e.g. `UUID('')` is not JSON serializable errors.

When `pk_field` attribute on `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` is not set, `to_representation` method simply returns `uuid.UUID` instance, see the related code:

```
class PrimaryKeyRelatedField(RelatedField):
    # ...

    def to_representation(self, value):
        if self.pk_field is not None:
            return self.pk_field.to_representation(value.pk)
        return value.pk
```

Source: https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/relations.py#L269-L272

**Why is it a problem**

As stated in other answers and comments, `JSONRenderer` will correctly handle this issue (http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#serializing-objects)

```
from rest_framework.renderers import JSONRenderer

json_data = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)
```

But there are situations when you do not want to use `JSONRenderer`:

- You're comparing `.data` during unit testing;
- You need to store `.data` in database, file, ...
- You want to post `.data` via `requests` to some API: `requests.post(..., json=serializer.data)`
- ...

**The solution**

Set `pk_field` attribute on `PrimaryKeyRelatedField` to `UUIDField()`:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from rest_framework.fields import UUIDField


class ExampleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(required=True,
                                            allow_null=False,
                                            # This will properly serialize uuid.UUID to str:
                                            pk_field=UUIDField(format='hex_verbose'))
```

And `uuid.UUID` instances will be correctly serialized to `str` when accessing `serializer.data`.

- http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield
- http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#uuidfield

Comment: It works! But in my case, I have to use `id  = serializers.UUIDField(format='hex')` to exclude UUID hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use, serializers.CharField

```
class ShiftSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     profile = serializers.CharField(read_only=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

UUID will be corrected when rendered by JSONRenderer.